# Parar funcionamento de um determinado trecho php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando parar o funcionamento de um determinado trecho do código. O exit, quanto die, param o bloco de código todo do foreach.

Só preciso que pare dentro do if, mas continue executando o foreach, depois volte nesses ifs, mas não executando o primeiro if

por exemplo

```
  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $item => $value){

            $this->return = '
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                       ';
                        if($value->nome_categoria === 'USERS') {
                            $this->return .= 'USERS';
                            $this->achouUsers = true;
                            while (!$this->achouUsers){
                                continue;
                            }

                        }

                        if($value->nome_categoria === "OPTIONS"){
                            $this->return .= 'OPTIONS';
                            $this->achouUsers = true;
                            while (!$this->achouOptions){
                                continue;
                            }
                        }


                        if( $value->nome_categoria === "MFP E CONNECTOR" ){
                            $this->return .= 'MFP E CONNECTOR';
                            while (!$this->achouMDF){
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    $this->return .= '
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">                            
                         <div class="col-lg-10">
                              <input type="radio" name="inputUsuarios">
                              '.utf8_encode($value->nome_item).'
                              '.(utf8_encode($value->nome_item) === 'Até' ? '<input type="text" > usuários <button  class=" btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> </button>' : '').'

                         </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-2 text-right">
                              '.number_format($value->valor_item,2,',','.').'
                         </div>
                    </div>                           

                </div>

                ';

            echo $this->return;
        }
```

executou o if do USERS apenas uma vez. a partir disso executasse tudo, e continuasse executando, mas testando ao invés do USERS, mas sim o OPTIONS

**EDIÇÃO 1**

O resultado esperado era algo do tipo

USERS
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OPTIONS
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparecendo a categoria apenas uma vez, o USERS em cima dessa imagem, o OPTIONS em cima dessa imagem e etc. Ele puxando do banco porém só aparecendo uma vez.

Com esse código meu retorno está sendo algo do tipo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse trecho de código está muito confuso e não parece fazer sentido. O que exatamente você precisa fazer? Digo isso no sentido de qual o resultado pretendido (e não no meio descrito na pergunta). Qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: Vou editar na pergunta a ideia

Comment: segue lá... a ideia, e o retorno como está vindo

Comment: Você sempre concatena em `return` o valor de `nome_categoria`, então por quê fazer o `if`?

Comment: a ideia seria para parar a execução do USERS, OPTIONS

Comment: Repara que ele ta vindo USERS, algo, USERS algo

Comment: Ok, acho que estou começando a entender. Todas essas opções são geradas a partir do laço, certo? Você quer que apareça o título `Users` no início e quando mudar o título você quer que apareça de novo, no caso, `Options`, etc?

Comment: Isso, exatamente isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde você faz:

```
if($value->nome_categoria === 'USERS') {
    $this->return .= 'USERS';
    $this->achouUsers = true;
    while (!$this->achouUsers){
        continue;
    }

}

if($value->nome_categoria === "OPTIONS"){
    $this->return .= 'OPTIONS';
    $this->achouUsers = true;
    while (!$this->achouOptions){
        continue;
    }
}

if( $value->nome_categoria === "MFP E CONNECTOR" ){
    $this->return .= 'MFP E CONNECTOR';
    while (!$this->achouMDF){
        continue;
    }
}
```

Como eu disse, não faz muito sentido esse código. Como todas as opções são geradas a partir do mesmo laço de repetição e você deseja que seja exibido o título sempre que mude a categoria, você pode criar uma variável extra de controle que mantém o nome da categoria atual e, quando for diferente, exibir novamente o título. Algo como:

```
if ($value->nome_categoria != $categoriaAtual) {
    $this->return .= $value->nome_categoria;
    $categoriaAtual = $value->nome_categoria;
}
```

Lembrando que antes do `foreach` é preciso iniciar a variável:

```
$categoriaAtual = "";
```

Comment: boa, obrigado, resolvido